# Jquery DataTable Sorting Numeric value column not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, datatable, datatables

In my Asp.net app, I have a Gridview Control and bind it on code behind.
And on client side I use `Jquery DataTable version 1.9.4` for better Sorting,Searching functionality, Here i got one problem Numeric value not sorting properly.

I googled and come to knw by using `sType": "numeric"`  will solved, but when i use this my whole working stoped my Column is at 9 position so i set `aTragets` 9

Here's the **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Pxwy/)**

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView3').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
       // "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [9] }]

       });
  });
```

[image]

[image]

Code nehind:
On Page_PreRender

```
if (GridView3.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView3.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            GridView3.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
```

On pageLoad :

```
GridView3.DataSource = sortedDT;
GridView3.DataBind();
```

Comment: do you have any numeric values separated by comma also? For ex 1,2 ?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy: No only decimal values, like `10.5, 13.5' and so on but their is no whitespace nor comma, i tried your solution but still not fixed

Comment: can you please paste the table data in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved:

**Gridview with Item template**:

In Item template their might be label control, so it convert into span, we need to remove that span tag ie html tag using `.contents().unwrap();`

Code:

```
$("#Gridview_ID span").contents().unwrap();
$('#Gridview_ID ').dataTable({
       "bJQueryUI": true,
       "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": false }, null, null, { "sType": "numeric" }, { "sType": "date" }, null, { "bSortable": false}]
         });
```

**Gridview with Bound Field:**

```
$('#Gridview_ID ').dataTable({
   "bJQueryUI": true,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": false }, null, null, { "sType": "numeric" }, { "sType": "date" }, null, { "bSortable": false}]
     });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think [aaSorting](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) is what you have to use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView3').dataTable({
      "aaSorting": [[ 9, "asc"]], /*row count starts from 0 in datatables*/
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
     // "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [9] }]

     });
});
```

**UPDATE**

The problem was as stated in my comment `It clearly does not understand the numeric datatype of the column`. Your problem is that inside your ... you had also text.

See a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Pxwy/1

Comment: Thank you for reply, its still not sorting properly, but now  using `"aaSorting": [[ 9, "asc"]],`  other functionality are working fine,

Comment: what exactly doesn't properly? Do you get errors? or is it datatables functionality problems?

Comment: also if you have any other initialization code show it also, so that we have a full picture of what you are doing and what might go wrong

Comment: I updated my question, i didnt get any error but sorting is not proper, as u can see both images `asc/desc` order for `billinglosthrs` column

Comment: I think that `decimal` values may cause problem

Comment: ok, thats easy. It clearly does not understand the numeric datatype of the column. `If DataTables is not detecting the numeric type, then it must be because you have non-numeric data somewhere in that column. This might be white-space, or some letters. ` Check out your data and surely you must have somewhere non-numeric data

Comment: Yes that `dot` (.) is their decimal value, so how i can solve this

Comment: i haven't used it my self but here you can find the answer http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/sorting_sType.html

Comment: The problem was as stated above in my comment ` It clearly does not understand the numeric datatype of the column`. Your problem is that inside your `<td>...</td>` you had also text. See a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Pxwy/1/

Comment: Thanks i solved it, earlier i was using Item template with a label inside my gridview so its convert into span, now i used BoundFiels and its working fine

Comment: @Satinder singh If my answer was helpfull maybe you could upvote it and accept it. Thanks