# Datatables sort numbers is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I use datatables on my page, it seems to work fine, except that when you do sorting on the number field, it sorts in a weird way, take a look at the illustration

[image]

This one also

[image]

I have tried to place

```
 "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": 'numeric',
            "oCustomInfo":{
    "decimalPlaces":1,
    "decimalSeparator":"."}
            },
            null
        ]
```

But this seems to further disturbs its behaviour as it becomes unsortable. Do you have a clue ?

Thanks

Comment: read the [sorting docs](http://datatables.net/development/sorting) and set type.... can find a lot with google...`datatables sort numbers`  ...including numerous posts on this topic in SO

Comment: Well, I have tried but non of the solutions seem to work.

Comment: try to remove the `aoColumns`-definition completely, it should work correct right away without it, _if there is not any of the rows that break the impression of a column with decmials_!! That is, for instance, **if some of the numbers have trailing blanks, and then is treated as strings**.

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for your reply, actually I didnt have the column definition at first, but it didnt work, the aoColumns was a work around that didnt work either :)

Comment: @Digitalfortress, I would say you should start trim the values of the column. I am 99.99% certain that you have either some whitespace or similar in at least one of the rows, and then the datatables sorting algorithm goes into "string"-mode. The problem is the data, not DataTables. Have been there too :)

Comment: Take a look in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761459/jquery-datatables-sort-numbers-only and example mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that for some reason the table data are treated as string and NOT as a number. Check the formatting of your values.

If fore example you have something like this:

```
<table .....>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
    </td>
    ....
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then Datatables will treat the value of that column as a string and not as a Number. This is common if you are outputting the text with a framework such as asp .NET.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832139/jquery-datatable-sorting-numeric-value-column-not-working-properly/16832408)  for a similar problem