# jQuery DataTables - sort numbers only

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using 1.10.1 and the new data-sort html5 attributes I want to ignore certain cells from the sort order.

My column is mixed with number and text values. Example:

```
<tr><td data-sort="100.50">100.50 USD</td></tr>
<tr><td data-sort="">Text</td></tr>
<tr><td data-sort="50.00">50.00 USD</td></tr>
```

When sorting on this column I want the text cells to be ignored. So descending order would be 100,50,Text. Ascending order would be 50,100,Text.

Can I accomplish this with the data-sort attributes only or is there another way?

Comment: doesnt' it do exactly that by `data-sort`? See this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/A3mcM/** or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @davidkonrad Hey, your example has the text data being at the top in sorting. I only want to sort by numbers, the text cells being at the bottom always

Comment: Yes, I did misunderstood :) I figured out a way to accomplish what you want, but not sure if it is sufficient. +1 for a great question!

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid this cannot be done with `data-sort` or `data-order` alone. DataTables will try to sort ascending / descending no matter what, and what you really need is actually two different sorting values for the plain text fields, making them either the highest or the lowest value.

However, thought you maybe could use a custom sorting plug-in for this instead? See the following plugin, that extracts any number from the column, or if a number is not present, setting the sorting value to either `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` (sorting descending) or `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` (sorting ascending) so plain text columns always are pushed to the bottom :

```js
function sortNumbersIgnoreText(a, b, high) {
    var reg = /[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?/;    
    a = a.match(reg);
    a = a !== null ? parseFloat(a[0]) : high;
    b = b.match(reg);
    b = b !== null ? parseFloat(b[0]) : high;
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));    
}
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "sort-numbers-ignore-text-asc": function (a, b) {
        return sortNumbersIgnoreText(a, b, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    },
    "sort-numbers-ignore-text-desc": function (a, b) {
        return sortNumbersIgnoreText(a, b, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) * -1;
    }
});
```

**Updated**. The code is cleaned up, and the plugin now sorts any kind of number, that is

- Integers, like 123
- Decimal numbers, like 123.45
- Negative and positive numbers, like -123.00, +123
- Scientific numbers, like 12.3e+10
- Illegal numbers, like 012345

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6qmkY/**

Comment: @Mark Steggles, have made a new answer. Now the plugin sorts integers, illegal numbers and scientific numbers as well, and the code has been cleaned up heavily.

Comment: This is REALLY great, thanks! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Looks like this does not work for dynamically populated datatables